# Delay Process of messages for x messages or x seconds

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, redis

I am using Kafka and Redis and I have a scenario where I want to wait when a specific user has 20 messages in the queue or wait x seconds and only then process those messages ( after I aggregate them )

How can I implement this?

thought to use pub/sub of Redis with a TTL but Redis pub-sub in case I don't have subscribers will not work well.

Comment: Which Kafka client are you using? Have you looked at Kafka producer `linger.ms` or `batch.size` property descriptions?

Comment: Kafka.js and yes but i want to do this per user not per partition.

Comment: Neither of those two properties are per-partition

Comment: meant per Topic sorry .

Comment: Those properties are per client. Clients can use multiple topics